# ASP.NET Core 6 Web Api Download File from IIS Server Performance

Tags: iis, download, asp.net-core-webapi

I actually can download a zip file from IIS(10) server by a customized web api.
Here is my simple HttpGet method

```
[HttpGet("download")]
public IActionResult DownloadFile()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(zipPath);
    return File(fileBytes , "application/octet-stream", "FileName.zip");
}
```

It takes ~6 minutes to download a ~80MB zip file via my API, however, if I just directly copy the zip file by remote apps, it only takes ~2 minutes.
I checked limit bandwidth setting is default in IIS manager, which is 4294967295(bytes/s), so the limit should not be the cause.

I'm wondering

1. What's difference between these two methods and why download is much more slowly via API?
2. How to improve download speed via API?

Comment: It's slow because you're **unnecessarily** reading the entire file into .NET's GC managed memory with `ReadAllBytes`) (which also causes memory to be copied at least twice, as .NET copies buffers from the OS-provided file IO buffers into its own managed GC area: your `Byte[]`), what's more and even worse: you're doing so synchronously (i.e. using blocking IO).

Comment: As you're using IIS, why not use IIS's built-in static file serving features? Set up a `<urlRewrite>` filesystem exclusion in your `web.config` for your `/download` path.

Comment: I'm curious about why rewriting the download path can get rid of unnecessarily reading? However, I add `match` and `action` elements in my `web.config` as `<match url="downloadPath" />` and `<action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:0}" />`. It seems not work, did I miss anything I needed?

Comment: There's no actual rewriting going on (it's just a name): IIS's URL-Rewriting module does more than rewrite request URLs: in this case it's being used to intercept a request before ASP.NET handles it, and sends the request off to IIS's built-in static-file-handler instead (because otherwise all requests _are_ eventually handled by ASP.NET/ASP.NET Core if you have a default IIS configuration).

Comment: I said to add a filesystem-based exclusion, but your `<action type="Rewrite"/>` rule is not a exclusion. Please read the documentation first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference - but first, please tell us where `zipPath` is coming from. Is it a fixed, constant value? or does it change?

Comment: `zipPath` is `C:\Windows\Temp\zipfile.zip` in VM server, purpose of my API is to merge a list of files, from another server, and compress them into a `.zip` file, and then response it.

Comment: Why on earth are you using `C:\Windows\Temp`? You should be using a per-app-pool temp directory which is handled for you automatically when you use `Path.GetTemporaryPath()` - so why aren't you doing things properly by using the appropriate API for temporary paths?

Comment: Also, if you use a hardcoded path into a temp directory you'll encounter race-conditions from when two concurrent requests end up writing to the same file on-disk... there's *a lot* of things you're doing incorrectly in your program code that is going to cause you problems in production.

Comment: TL;DR: Use `ControllerBase.PhysicalFile`, not `File`.

Comment: Probably I didn't make it clear, `zipPath` is `Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP"), "myFile.zip")`. However, I tested `ControllerBase.PhysicalFile` performance in `GET` request and it was the same result. As you mentioned, `myFile.zip` is not static since my API must deal with it so I should not exclude it from filesystem, right? Anyway, muti-requests is an issue and should be fixed later on.

Comment: So you're saying that you're seeing download speeds of `227KB/s` (which is `80MB / 360s` == `81920 / 360`)? I cannot explain that, sorry. It's possible something else is interfering with things. What happens if you physically move the file into your webroot (Your project's `wwwroot` directory) and let IIS's `StaticFileModule` serve it? If that's also slow that-way then something is seriously wrong with your set-up, which is outside the scope of this question - and our abilities to diagnose given the information you've posted.